# Update a record in database after delete with Sequelize Model and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, sequelize.js

i created a controller that can delete but it is difference because it is not only delete records according ID, it also update the record after the API of delete is call.
Let me demonstrate my code below:

```
// delete user
exports.delete = (req, res) => {
  const user_id = req.params.user_id;

  // Find record by it is id to DELETE
  User.findByPk(user_id).then((num) => {
    if (num == 1) {
      res.status(200).send({
        message: "User was deleted successfully!",
        data: null,
      });
    } else {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: `Cannot delete User with id=${user_id}. Maybe User was not found!`,
        data: null,
      });
    }
  });

  //After delete must update the is_active field
  User.update(
    {
      is_active: 0,
    },
    {
      where: { is_active: null },
    }
  );
};
```

Now i have problem that i do not know how to make my API to work. So, i hope someone can help me to deal with this problem that how to update `is_active` MUST BE 0 after DELETE. I am appreciate it.

Comment: Where is the delete call?

Comment: I do not understand, could you be more specific ?

Comment: You created `delete user` route handler, right? Where do you delete a user? I see only `update`

Comment: Yeah, my delete controller is not delete the record, it special because this controller is work like this: when you delete a record, you will find by it ID and then when you delete it, the is_active must be 0. That's why is tricky than the other delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `async/await` instead of `then` to wait for then result of `findByPk` before calling `update`:

```js
exports.delete = async (req, res) => {
  const user_id = req.params.user_id;

  // Find record by it is id to DELETE
  const user = await User.findByPk(user_id)

  if (user) {
    //After delete must update the is_active field
    await User.update(
      {
        is_active: 0,
      },
      {
        where: { is_active: null },
      }
    );
    res.status(200).send({
      message: "User was deleted successfully!",
      data: null,
    });
  } else {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: `Cannot delete User with id=${user_id}. Maybe User was not found!`,
        data: null,
      });
  }
};
```

This way you have a straight forward code like you usually write when it's synchronous.